# Meteor:Pagination How to provide dynamic value for filter condition of alethes:pages

Tags: javascript, meteor, pagination

Structure of User Collection

```
profiles: {
{
_id : "1",
accountid: "acc1",
modifiedOn: Tue Dec 29 2015 15:01:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
users: [
    {
        status: "New",
        userid: "User 1",
        username: "Harry"
    },
    {
        status: "Old",
        userid: "User 2",
        username: "Stephen"
    }
]
},
{
    _id : "2",
    accountid: "acc2",
    modifiedOn: Tue Dec 29 2015 15:01:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    users: [
    {
        status: "New",
        userid: "U1",
        username: "Potter"
    },
    {
        status: "Old",
        userid: "U2",
        username: "Hawkings"
    }
]
}
}



Profile = new new Mongo.Collection("profiles");

Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Profile, {
perPage: 2,    
templateName: "userTemplate",
itemTemplate: "itemUserTemplate"
});
```

Do we have any means to give dynamic filter value to the alethes:pages pagination something like this?

Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Profile, {
    perPage: 2,
    filters: {
        accountid: {
            $eq : 
        }
    }, 
    templateName: "userTemplate",
    itemTemplate: "itemUserTemplate"
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can modify the filter after declaring the collection like this:

```
Pages.set({filters: your_query});
```

This can be called anywhere on the client, so you can set your query with a `ReactiveVar` and call `Pages.set` inside a `Tracker.autorun` to make it reactive.

Comment: Thanks for your information David. I used the set method along with **availableSettings: {filters: true}** in the Pagination constructor to get the job done.

@DavidKleiman Is there any way like just returning the array in the collection directly instead of getting the collection object via Pagination instance like getting the **users** array alone instead of getting the **Profile** collection which matches the dynamic query in set method.